# Как вывести все данные из таблицы?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, visual-studio-2015

У меня есть метод который выбирает все из таблицы Book. Как мне возвращать или вывести все данные который выбрал Select?

```
        public SqlDataReader Selectsql()
    {
        Book ass = new Book();
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = mydatabase; Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        Array a;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books Where Id = '2'";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //return reader;
    }
```

Comment: [прочитайте вот это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx). Вся необходимая информация в этой статье имеется.